# How to translate and use values in array order?

Tags: angular-translate

I have a string "Hello, my name is {0}. I'm from {1}" and a sorted array ["Michael", "Berlin"].

I want to put the first array element in {0}, the second in {1}, and so on. How can I achieve this with angular-translate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert your array from simple "keyless" sorted to a nice json associative object, it will be easier to use a template like

```
Hello, my name is {name}. I'm from {city}
```

and then let the module do the work e.g. through the directive (taking over the array definition from the other answer):

```
<span translate translate-values="{'name': vm.array[0], 'city': vm.array[1]}"></span>
```

Using this approach, you'll get what you want. But it would be advisable to take a  structured object already at the beginning instead of a simple array.

Documentation on the replacement functionality can be found [here](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text you want to translate in different strings and translate them seperately.

```
var app = angular.module('moduleName', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    'HELLO': 'Hello, my name is ',
    'IM_FROM': 'Im from '
  });
  $translateProvider.translations('fr', {
    //your translation in other languages
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});
```

You can read the documentations here : [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)

In your controller define your array :

```
vm.array = ["Michael", "Berlin"]
```

In your html:

```
<div translate="HELLO"></div>{{vm.array[0]}}. 
<div translate="IM_FROM"></div>{{vm.array[1]}}
```